# Sort nested dictionary in ascending order and grab outer key?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
dictionary = {'article1.txt': {'harry': 3, 'hermione': 2, 'ron': 1},
 'article2.txt': {'dumbledore': 1, 'hermione': 3},
 'article3.txt': {'harry': 5}}
```

And I'm interested in picking the article with the most number of occurences of Hermione. I already have code that selects the outer keys (`article1.txt`, `article2.txt`) and inner key `hermione`.

Now I want to be able to have code that sorts the dictionary into a list of ascending order for the highest number occurrences of the word `hermione`. In this case, I want a list such that `['article1.txt', 'article2.txt']`. I tried it with the following code:

```
#these keys are generated from another part of the program
keys1 = ['article1.txt', 'article2.txt']
keys2 = ['hermione', 'hermione']
place = 0
for i in range(len(keys1)-1):
    for j in range(len(keys2)-1): 
        if articles[keys1[i]][keys2[j]] > articles[keys1[i+1]][keys2[j+1]]:
            ordered_articles.append(keys1[i])
            place += 1
        else:
            ordered_articles.append(place, keys1[i])
```

But obviously (I'm realizing now) it doesn't make sense to iterate through the keys to check if `dictionary[key] > dictionary[next_key]`. This is because we would never be able to compare things not in sequence, like `dictionary[key[1]] > dictionary[key[3]]`.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're trying to do is **sort** the articles by the amount of 'hermiones' in them. And, python has a built-in function that does exactly that (you can check it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)). You can use it to sort the dictionary keys by the amount of hermiones each of them points to.

Here's a code you can use as example:

```
# filters out articles without hermione from the dictionary
# value here is the inner dict (for example: {'harry': 5})
dictionary = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if 'hermione' in value}

# this function just returns the amount of hermiones in an article
# it will be used for sorting
def hermione_count(key):
    return dictionary[key]['hermione']

# dictionary.keys() is a list of the keys of the dictionary (the articles)
# key=... here means we use hermione_count as the function to sort the list
article_list = sorted(dictionary.keys(), key=hermione_count)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get by without having to defining the function `hermione_count(key)`?

Comment: For context: I might get more than one word (i.e ['hermione', 'dumbledore'] in the code. I think `sorted(dictionary, keys)` will work, but I'm not quite sure what other function to put into `keys`

Comment: You mean, you wanna get the amount of 'hermione' and 'dumbledore' together?

Like {'hermione': 1, 'dumbledore': 2} equals 3 ?

Comment: If that's the case, then, you can simply use: dictionary[key]['hermione'] + dictionary[key]['dumbledore']

Comment: Luis Yup, that's what I was looking for. Would I use that as a return in the defined function?

Comment: Yep, just like with one word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141602/discussion-between-andre-luis-and-nikitau).